# How do I change default notification settings for a Discord channel?

Tags: notifications, discord

I've set up my Discord server to only send message notifications to a user if they are explicitly ***@mentioned*** by name in a conversation.

[image: Server notification settings]

I had originally had notifications on for **All Messages** by default, but this became an issue after we added a chat-controlled music bot to the server.

[image: We got notifications for every single message]

I don't want to spam chat notifications for channels like ***#bot-commands***. But I do want to make sure notifications are turned on for important channels like ***#announcements*** or ***#general***.

**As a server owner, is there a way to turn notifications on or off by default for a specific channel?**

Comment: If you want to support this feature getting implemented, consider visiting the feature request topic: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360041537711--Server-Setting-Channel-Notification?page=1

Answer (score 7):

**Unfortunately, default notification settings can only be applied on a per-server basis in the current version of Discord.**

---

One workaround is to mention ***@here*** or ***@everyone*** any time someone has an important announcement.

[image: Notifying @everyone in a server]

***@here*** notifies all non-idle members currently online

***@everyone*** notifies all members regardless of status

---

It's also worth noting that, if a user doesn't like ***@everyone*** notifications, [they can disable it themselves on a per-server basis](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/215253148-How-do-I-stop-everyone-mentions-from-select-servers-) in Notification Settings.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this so anyone seeing this in the future knows; Discord (at least the current version) has configurable "Categories" within which you can set a default notification type (All notifications, only @ mentions, none).

You can right click by the channel panel to create a new category, assign the notification type you want to that category, and then every channel that gets added to that category will use that category's default notification type. Note that server members will still be able to change the channel's notifications settings for themselves.

[Creating a category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihNdd.png)

[Setting category notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcL97.png)

[Category default used in channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLyZ.png)

Comment: Future here, appreciated!

Comment: Perfect answer, perfect feature

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer exactly to your question but a workaround.

You can use a sticky bot that follows up on every message. It can then @mention any role you'd like to be triggered.

Usually sticky bots delete their own previous message so it won't clutter the channel more than one message.